# Xamarin Forms ZXing error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

Hi I am trying to use ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms in my project. However it is showing the following error

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Element.set_AutomationId' not found

This is using the code from the sample.

```
var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage ();

scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
    // Stop scanning
    scanPage.IsScanning = false;

    // Pop the page and show the result
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        Navigation.PopAsync ();        
        DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
    });
};

// Navigate to our scanner page
await Navigation.PushAsync (scanPage);
```

Comment: Do you have Linker enabled? If so try disable it and see if that works.

Comment: Linker is disabled. No luck

Comment: I assume you used the nuget package to install it, right?   If so, make sure you installed it on your PCL and you other projects as well (Android, IOS, Windows)

Comment: what line is the error happening on?

Comment: It is failing at line 1.

Comment: Is this happening on Android or iOS? And what version of Forms and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms are you using?

Comment: Xamarin forms 2.0.0.6490

Comment: ZXing 2.1.47. I have only tried on android so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Xamarin.Forms doesn't support automation id before version 2.2. Updating fixed the error.